# Convergence by Vitali's theorem?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a compact subset of $\Bbb R^3$, $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$. I want to show that 
$$
\int_{\Omega} |u_m-u|^2 (|\nabla u_m|+|\nabla u|)^4 d\mu \to 0
$$
as $m\to\infty$. It is given that $u,u_m\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ while $\nabla u,\nabla u_m\in L^4(\Omega)$. We also have $u_m\to u$ in $L^2$ (and almost everywhere) and $\nabla u_m\to\nabla u$ in $L^2$. Moreover, $\nabla u_m\overset{w}\to \nabla u$ weakly in $L^4$ so $||\nabla u_m||_{L^4}<C$ uniformly for some $C>0$.

It appears that this follow somehow from Vitali's theorem but I don't see how. Any help is extremely appreciated.

PS. The probability tag is from the fact that I often see Vitali's theorem used there, and this question can be interpreted in term of random variables if one wish.

Comment: This looks very very false. If you knew that the $L^4$ norm of $\nabla u_m$ was bounded, then maybe one could do something. But just knowing that $\nabla u, \nabla u_m \in L^4$ does not tell you much...

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks, I forgot to say that the norm are bounded uniformly. Will edit right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed one can prove your claim by Vitali's theorem, however a direct estimate already gives the claim if one uses the compact Sobolev embedding $W^{1,4}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^\infty(\Omega)$ for a bounded domain $\Omega$ of dimension $d \leq 3$:
$$\begin{align}
&\quad\int_\Omega |u_m - u|^2 (|\nabla u_m| + |\nabla u|)^4 d\mu \\&\leq C \|u_m - u\|_{L^\infty}^2 \cdot \int_{\Omega}(|\nabla u_m|^4 + |\nabla u|^4)d\mu \\
&\leq C' \|u_m - u\|_{L^\infty}^2 \quad\longrightarrow 0 \quad\text{for}\quad m\to\infty,
\end{align}
$$
where $C,C'>0$ denote constants independent of $m$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is my understanding correct that we can dispense the Sobolev embedding part if we assume a priori that $||u_m-u||$ is uniformly bounded in $L^{\infty}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Indeed, it „feels a bit overkill“ to use strong $L^\infty$-convergence just to conclude uniform boundedness of $\|u_m - u\|_{L^\infty}$ :)

Comment: If you are satisfied by my answer you might as well consider accepting it ;)

Comment: Definitely. One last question, if you don't mind. I am not very familiar with Vitali's theorem, could you please elaborate a bit more on the precise statement of the theorem that you used?

Comment: Also I don't understand how you got the last inequality. I know that weak convergence in $L^4$ implies $||\nabla u||_4\le \lim\inf ||\nabla u_m||_4$ but you seemed to use the reverse of that.

Comment: I appended a version of Vitali's Theorem. The last step in the chain of inequalities is an application of Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: I might be saying something funny here, but doesn't Fatou's lemma give the reverse inequality of what we want?

Comment: I guess you are having the "$\liminf$"-version of Fatou's Lemma in mind. I used the statement that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \int f_n \leq \int \limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n$ for any sequence of non-negative measurable functions $f_n$.

Comment: Don't we need a dominating function of some sort to apply that version of the lemma?

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I thought the existence of a dominating function was not necessary over finite measure spaces but this does not seem plausible to me now. Let me think about this. Nevertheless, one can also show the convergence over a similiar direct argument which is appended.

Comment: I think this part is a bit more tricky than we'd expected, please let me know if you manage to fix it. Even though the answer is not 100% complete, I learnt quite a few things from it so I'll accept this. Thanks again.

Comment: The "Alternative Argument" definitely settles convergence (I am quite embarassed I didn't see it right away :D). I will try to fix the Vitali-argument tomorrow.

Comment: I must apologize but the question as stated is not exactly what I wanted to ask. My domain is actually of dimension $2+1$ with time dimension while the $\nabla u$ is only derivative in space, so we don't really have enough to apply Sobolev embedding. The uniform bounded on $||u_m-u||_{\infty}$ is assured through other mean though. I think we really need Vitali here.

Comment: You're answer now is totally correct for this version of the question though :)

Comment: The compact Sobolev embedding $W^{1,4} \hookrightarrow L^\infty$ holds for all dimensions $\leq 3$, that is also for $n=2$.

Comment: I mean we lack the information on $\partial_t u$, we only have $\nabla u\in L^4(\Omega)$, i.e. we aren't really in $W^{1,4}(\Omega)$. The original question is based on a certain parabolic pde, so we can somehow prove $\partial_t u\in L^2(\Omega)$. This means that we're in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ and we can only embed up to $L^6(\Omega)$.

Comment: Ah, the time-dependence is also included in $\Omega$?

Comment: My notation is a bit confusing I must admit, what I wanted to say was $\Omega = S\times [0,T]$ where $S$ is some $2$-dimensional surface.

Comment: Okay, I just removed the Vitali argument and gave the "direct" estimate. I hope the answer is still fine in way. Maybe you open up another question for your problem regarding the time dependent function.